# Maven update project and dependencies

Tags: java, maven

In an application that worked until now, I run in Eclipse the command Maven->Update project and I started getting errors.

I tried to fix it by deleting all the local repository and running  Maven->Update project again. But these are the errors that I still see in my Markers view:

```
Missing artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6

Missing artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6

ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of 

ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of 

Error occured processing XML 'org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor'. See Error Log for more details
```

The code hasn't changed and worked fine before.

Any idea on how I can fix these errors?

Comment: did you try to delete the project .classpath?

Comment: try to delete slf4j from your local repo

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the particular mentioned jar.
But when you do build you should be connected to internet cause some external jar referred in POM get downloaded while building your project.
Also please check whether the mentioned jar is is maven repository or not.
Above jar is related to slf4j so i think it will be resolved if you are connected to internet .

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the SL4J jar is partially downloaded in your maven local repository. Try deleting it if it exists in the local repository. If that fails try creating a new dir called repository; mine is stored in ~/.m2 (ubuntu). Out of paranoia I rename the current dir as not to lose the jars already inside it.